# A Spontaneous Reaction with greater ordering

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

I wanted to ask a question regarding entropy in a reaction.

I was given the reaction

$2H_{2}$ (g) + $O_{2}$ (g) $\rightarrow$ $2H_{2}O$ (l)

and asked:

> the overall process is spontaneous but the system becomes more ordered. Explain why
>   the $∆S^{⦵}<0$, linking your answer to different forms of available entropy to the reactants and product, their relative magnitudes and how the phase of each molecule affects these entropies.

So I was thinking that there is rotational, vibrational and translational entropy available.

Given that the ${H_2}$ and ${O_2}$ molecules are in a gas phase, they would have the greatest entropy in all $3$ types of energies, and water being in the liquid phase would have lower entropy in all $3$ types of energies.

The answer given to this question gives a similar outline

> All three molecules would possess translational, rotational and
>   vibrational entropy, translational would be the smallest energetically
>   followed by rotational and then vibrational. The reactants are both in
>   the gas phase and so their translational and rotational entropies would
>   be much greater than the corresponding terms for water as it is in the
>   liquid phase. The water molecules have greatly reduced translational
>   and rotational freedom and hence these respective entropies will be
>   significantly smaller. The vibrational entropies for all three molecules
>   would be of an equivalent order of magnitude.

But apparently the vibrational entropies don't have as much of an effect - i.e. for all $3$ molecules, they are roughly equivalent.

This has been bugging me for the whole day - I thought in the vibrational state, seeing as there is more energy in the gaseous phase, my reactant ${H_2}$ and ${O_2}$ would have greater vibrational entropy too.

Why is the vibrational energy *of the same magnitude* for all 3 molecules?